# MVC: access attribute value in action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

MVC 4

I have an action that is decorated with an action filter like this:

```
    [ViewPermission(PermissionType.GlobalUser)]
    public ActionResult General()
    {

        var permissionType = // trying to access the value passed to the filter ie. PermissionType.GlobalUser value

        return View();
    }
```

Is there a way to get the properties from the acation filter inside the action itself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the quick answer is yes, you can do it doing something like this:

```
[ViewPermission(PermissionType.GlobalUser)]
public ActionResult General()
    {
        var type = GetType(this);
        var method = type.GetMethod("General");
        var attribute(typeof(ViewPermission));
        var permissionType = attribute.PermissionType;

        return View();
    }
```

With that said, it is NOT a good idea.  Doing reflection is slow.  Very slow.  You would see performance problems.  If you really need to do this, then it is best to figure out a way to do it during initialization of the app, where performance is not as much of a concern.

Hope that helps.